# Number of point to point link

Tags: communication, wireless, telecommunications

I dont know if this is unrelevant here but i wish if someone could help me .

> The number of point to point links required in a fully connected network for 50 entities is
>
> (a) 1250
>   (b) 1225
>   (c) **2500**
>   (d) 50

My answer is 1225 but its 2500 every where in internet .
As per i know the mathematics is n(n-1)/2 but every where its 2500 , I dont know what is the concept i am missing .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us how you arrived to 1225. Even if it is the wrong answer.

Comment: i have given my logic n(n-1)/2 where i put n as 50

Comment: Also, who exactly is saying that it's 2500? That is incorrect, *unless* the links are one way

Comment: if you search the question on internet every website in internet have option with 2500 as answer ...

Comment: @pravinpoudel Woaw, not sure how I missed that. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on your definition of "fully connected network". If the normal meaning is used, where each connection is bidirectional, then the answer is 1225.

It's possible that the questioner is using a weird definition where each link is unidirectional, in which case the answer would be 50*50=2500. This would (I think) be very unusual, and it's more likely that the questioner just made a mistake. If this were ever asked in a formal setting, I would say 1225, and if marked as wrong, I would complain to the examining body.

It's probable that the results you're seeing on the internet have all been copied from the same incorrect source.

Comment: It would actually be 50*49=2450